# Apexcharts Heatmap: display exact x value on hover for each series data

Tags: javascript, heatmap, apexcharts

I'm trying to create a heatmap using apexcharts that shows frequency of activites each week in a year (Check the github contributions heatmap). My goal is to display a tooltip that shows the **specific date**, **week day**, and **frequency value** whenever the user hovers on a cell. Example:

```
 ------------
| 2022-02-20 |
| ---------- |
| Sunday: 40 |
 ------------
```

This is what I have attempted so far:

```
var options = {
    series: [],
    chart: {
      height: 350,
      type: 'heatmap',
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true
    },
    xaxis: {
      labels: {
        show: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false,
      },
    },
    tooltip: {
      shared: false,
      followCursor: true,
      intersect: false,
      x: {
        show: true,
        format: 'dd MMM'
      },
    }
};
```

Here is a simplified sample series:

```
var series = [
    {
    name: 'Sunday',
    data: [{
        x: '2022-02-20',
        y: 40
        }]
    },
    {
    name: 'Monday',
    data: [{
        x: '2022-02-21',
        y: 0
        }]
    },
    {
    name: 'Tuesday',
    data: [{
        x: '2022-02-22',
        y: 5
        }]
    },
    {
    name: 'Wednesday',
    data: [{
        x: '2022-02-23',
        y: 100
        }]
    },
    {
      name: 'Thursday',
      data: [{
        x: '2022-02-24',
        y: 17
      }]
    },
    {
      name: 'Friday',
      data: [{
        x: '2022-02-25',
        y: 4
      }]
    },
    {
      name: 'Saturday',
      data: [{
        x: '2022-02-26',
        y: 90
      }]
    },
];
options.series = series;
```

What happens here is that the apexcharts displays a heatmap for the week of 2022-02-20 (Sunday) to 2022-02-26 (Saturday) vertically from bottom to top (it seems it displays in reverse order). If the user hovers to the Sunday cell it displays the exact tooltip that I provided at the beginning with the values 2022-02-20, Sunday, and 40. However, when the user hovers on cells Monday - Saturday, the tooltip displays the correct values except for the x value. It still displays 2022-02-20.

From what I understand, the chart treats the first x value in a column as the column's **category**. This means regardless on whether the user hovers to Saturday, or Friday, or any other day it will display the Sunday's x value. What can I do to display the actual x value of the hovered cell?

**Update**

Here's a demonstration of the heatmap

[image: Apexcharts Heatmap Demo]

**Update as of 2022-03-01**

As suggested by @Patryk Laszuk, I added

```
formatter: (value,options)=>{
   return options.w.config.series[options.seriesIndex].data[0].x
}
```

on `tooltip.x`, however this makes all the cells aligned horizontally have the same x value.

Comment: Was just about to embark on building a similar chart. Were you able to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `formatter` https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/tooltip/#xformatter

```
tooltip: {
  ...
  x: {
    ...
    formatter: (value,options)=>{
      return options.w.config.series[options.seriesIndex].data[0].x
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It fixed the heatmap but for 1 column only. This time, when there are multiple columns (all dates in a year just like the github contributions heatmap) displayed at once, every row will have the same x value. Meaning all tuesday cells will have the same x value of the first tuesday of the year (its 2022-01-04 for the current year). I'll add this as an update

Comment: `options.w.config.series[options.seriesIndex].data[options.dataPointIndex].x` 
my bad, instead of 0 it should be dataPointIndex